# How to access Active directory from within SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, active-directory

I have a need to extract/retrieve a list of AD users for the company. I have full access (developer access) to a SQL Server database (which I believe is equivalent to an Oracle schema?). I **do not** full rights to administer it like a DBA.

1. I've searched the net and came across various guides and most use `use master` in the code. And even if I am not familiar with SQL Server, does this means I need dba-like access to a SQL server installation? **It would be nice if you can include working code as well.**
2. I am thinking of creating a SQL Server view to store the data. Is this possible? I suppose it is but just want to check. I've seen some examples but it's from way back 2003. A lot could've changed since then.
3. Anything else you think I might need?

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this in the past to query AD users.

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    OPENROWSET('ADSDSOObject', 
           '127.0.0.1';
           'domain\username';'password', 
           'SELECT 
                distinguishedName, 
                manager, 
                objectGUID, 
                samAccountName, 
                givenName, 
                SN, 
                mail 
            FROM 
                ''LDAP://127.0.0.1/DC=namepart,DC=namepart'' 
            WHERE 
                objectClass=''User'' 
            AND objectCategory=''Person'' 
');
```

You need to first enable ad-hoc distributed queries.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries',1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
```

Answer (score -2):

Basically: you do not. Run that from a program, do not run it from within SQL Server. If needed regularly, sync a table in SQL Server with data you extract from AD.

> I've search the net and came across various guides and most use "use
>   master" in the code. And even if I am not familiar with SQL Server,
>   does this means I need dba-like access to a SQL server installation?
>   It would be nice if you can include working code as well.

Consider maybe reading some documentation at some point in your career. "use master" is exactly that - it tells SQL Server to USE the database named MASTER. As all operations are executed in the current database (context) this puts this context to a known location. For some things this can be good as dropping the current database can lead to issues, so some stuff is better done by changing the current context first. All this is in the documentation.

> I am thinking of creating a SQL Server view to store the data.

Do you know SQL? No view ever anywhere STORES data. It may materialize it, but it never STORES. This is what TABLES do. Views are like macros.

> Anything else you think I might need?

Documentation. Reading. You miss basics of ANY SQL server in implementation I know of - neither Oracle, nor Informix, DB2, Microsoft SQL Server.) VIEW is NOT a primary data store. Basics.

And in general, do not try to access AD from within any database server.

Comment: Actually yes you can. You can query AD from SQL Server by setting it up as a linked server and using `OPENQUERY` and it works very well, although writing the queries can be a pain as you end up in quote mark hell. There is no good reason why you should not access AD from a DB server: It's just another data store. Of course if the OP has no admin rights then they'll need their DBA to set up the linked server as per [this walkthrough](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2580/querying-active-directory-data-from-sql-server/).

Comment: @StevePettifer: that feature is both (a) very limited (cannot access any multi-valued attributes in AD), and (b) deprecated, so I would definitely recommend against starting new development using this....

Comment: @marc_s True, but you can query them. That said, I hadn't realised it was being deprecated which is an excellent reason not to use it and something the answer should have addressed rather than the somewhat condescending 'do not do it' statement with no explanation. CLR integration is probably the way to go then.